# how to conditionally change xAxes display format in chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, vue.js

enter image description herehow can i conditionally render label on xAxes in chart.js for example if difference between first and last timestamp is more than 1 year then it uses format "May 2020", May '2021, May '2022", otherwise "25 Jan, 25 Jun, 25 Nov"
There is a date imput field where the user can select a start date and an end date. depending on the time difference of the start and end dates the labels should look like on the image

Comment: Could you give a minimal reproducible example, please?

Comment: well, i do not have the code for minimal example but i will attach images of what i am looking for